# Building single Maven modules is not implemented for Maven 3, yet

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, webdriver

I am getting this error while running selenium script in jenkins:

```
Building in workspace /home/jenkins_home/jobs/fe-integration-test/workspace
$ /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_34/bin/java -cp /home/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4 /opt/wikiandsonartomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.16.jar /home/jenkins_home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 42127
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Building single Maven modules is not implemented for Maven 3, yet!
Finished: ABORTED'
```

My server is CENT OS.
Can any one tell me how to get out of this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven build is aborted in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218184/maven-build-is-aborted-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause comes from [Jenkins maven-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/maven/MavenBuild.java), so it should be fixed there first.

As of 2014-03-12 the code seems to have been improved.

Answer (score 1):

Today I got around this error by simply restarting Jenkins service (windows 7).